# How can I combine in one file multiple .py and.ui files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, exe, qt-designer

I have bilingual application. In QtDesigner I made two interfaces: gui_eng.ui and gui_rus.ui. For each of them exist main_gui_eng.py and main_gui_rus.py files with  configuration code of those .ui files. What is more, there exists main.py file (from which is started main_gui_eng.py or main_gui_rus.py according to last time closed). main.py will be converted to .exe file.
In each file I use following way to connect with .ui:

```
main_window = uic.loadUiType('gui_eng.ui')[0]
class WIZWindow(QMainWindow, main_window):
```

Problem: How could I connect them this way? If I write in main.py:

```
import main_gui_eng
```

it does not open needed .ui file...

Comment: You do realize that is what that translation functionality is all about -- you do not need to completely different UIs you just need two translation functions (one for each language) and then dependent upon the language chosen access the appropriate translation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 `pyuic5 gui_eng.ui -o gui_eng.py`

2 `pyuic5 gui_rus.ui -o gui_rus.py`

3 `python main_eng_rus.py`

4 `pyinstaller -c -F main_eng_rus.py`

5 `main_eng_rus.exe`

---

**main_gui_eng.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

# pyuic5 gui_eng.ui -o gui_eng.py
from gui_eng import Ui_MainWindow


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.parent.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setWindowTitle("main_gui_eng.py")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main_gui_rus.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

# pyuic5 gui_rus.ui -o gui_rus.py
from gui_rus import Ui_MainWindow


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent 

        self.setupUi(self)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.hide()
        self.parent.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.setWindowTitle("main_gui_rus.py")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main_eng_rus.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, 
                             QWidget, QGridLayout)

from main_gui_eng import Window as gui_eng
from main_gui_rus import Window as gui_rus


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.button_eng = QPushButton('Open main_gui_eng.py')
        self.button_eng.clicked.connect(self.open_gui_eng)
        self.button_rus = QPushButton('Open main_gui_rus.py')
        self.button_rus.clicked.connect(self.open_gui_rus)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button_eng, 0, 0)         
        self.grid.addWidget(self.button_rus, 0, 1)

    def open_gui_eng(self):
        self.mainGuiEng = gui_eng(self)
        self.mainGuiEng.show()
        self.hide()

    def open_gui_rus(self):
        self.mainGuiRus = gui_rus(self)
        self.mainGuiRus.show()
        self.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("main_eng_rus.py")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]